# C++ how to put an input string from stdio into a vector, one word per container element

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++, and I'm a bit of a newbie. I've researched this question quite a bit. I've studied vectors, strings, and stringstreams in c++ but I still can't find the 'right' way to do this.

Basically, I want to write, "some text" at the command line and have "some" put into a vector container at position '0' and "text" put into the same container in position '1'.

I've found a lot of ways that sorta work, but nothing that just does that.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line); // read one line from cin
    std::stringstream buffer(line);
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    // copy each word from line to words
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(buffer),
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
              std::back_inserter(words));
}
```

Comment: Instead of the `std::copy`, a simple `while(buffer >> string) words.push_back(string)` would work as well. Compare that version with DeadMG's version, and you'll see that the difference is that the above code is creating a streamstring with the content of one line, while DeadMG uses std::cin. (Alternatively, one could rewrite DeadMG's code to use the `std::copy`)

Comment: @Sjoerd: I think Björn and Dead just interpred the specification differently. Both are valid interpretations as the specifications are unclear on the exact nature of what is needed. Given the choice I would use std::copy() rather than a manual while loop (as I think it is simpler). Try writing both interpretation of the spec with while and copy. The version with copy is always simpler (once you have used it once or twice it becomes natural).

Comment: @LokiAstari I just wanted to make the two examples more comparable, to emphasis the difference in setting up the stream. I could have been clearer about that, though.

Comment: @LokiAstari (different comment to separate the discussion) Although I usually prefer to use <algorithm> over hand-crafted loops, in this case the `while` might be easier to understand to "a bit of a newbie." Introducing std::back_inserter and std::istream_iterator will distract from the answer to 'how to set up the stream?'

Comment: @Bjorn - Thanks, this works just as I want it to. I appreciate your help.  If you have a little more time, I'd like to ask you a couple of questions about your code. First, why do you use the std:: form instead of "using namespace std;" ? I notice quite a few experienced programmers do that. Lastly, why is your code copying words and not chars? How are you telling it to use white-space as a delimiter? Thanks

Comment: @LokiAstari and Sjoerd - the main difference between this and DeadMG's version is that the carriage return works to send the line to the rest of the program in Bjorn's version and not in DeadMG's version. This was what I was mainly having trouble with. I realized that the issue of breaking out of a while-loop with a CR may not be something most programmers run into. Maybe this loop is mostly used for entering info into fields before a user presses a 'submit' btn.

Comment: @bev: Using `std` everywhere is just a habit of mine for code I post here. The general rule is that it is OK to have `using namespace std;` in a cpp-file, but *never* in a header-file (this would polute the global namespace of those that include that header). Second: When extracting an `string` from an `istream` (which is what `istream_iterator<string>` does), it always reads until the next white-space - that's just of it is implemented.

Comment: @BjörnPollex - Ah, I see a great light. Thanks for all the help, Bjorn.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `>>` to achieve this effect.

```
std::vector<std::string> vector;
std::string string;
while(std::cin >> string)
    vector.push_back(string);
```

Comment: Y'know, I'm beginning to think that there's something wrong with my g++ implementation. Online there are a lot of similar solutions to your's, DeadMG. The problem is that if I do $> Hi there. it is still waiting for more input. I need it to stop waiting for more input after I hit CR. Your solution won't put the input into the vector and then return to the prompt. I want the words I type in at the prompt to be entered, put into a vector and that's it. Prompt is back. Any ideas? Thx

Comment: @bev: You're going to have to be a lot more specific and clear. Also, your original question didn't really mention any additional requirements.

Comment: @bev DeadMG's code reads till the end of the file, not the end of the line. To include an EOF in the stream, press CTRL-D (Linux/Unix) or press CTRL-Z (Windows) at the start of a new line.

Comment: @DeadMG code works perfectly. The problem is that the standard input (std::cin) is buffered. Which means what you type goes into a buffer and when the buffer is full is flushed so that code can use it (or it is forcefully flushed when you hit enter). But either way the program is halted until the buffer is flushed. This is just the way the streams work, you can not get around that without using platform specific code.

Comment: @DeadMG - sorry about being insufficiently specific. One of the skills you gain as you learn new things is how to ask questions such that you'll get the answer you need from those who already know that thing. My reply to your comment has all the rest of the specs. Basically, I want to enter some text on the command line and then hit CR. At that point the text will be placed into a vector, one word per container element (as opposed to one char). I could do this with a conditional statement if I knew how to match a CR in a stream to something I could put in an if statement. (more ->)

Comment: ASCII code doesn't seem to work. This seems like such a simple thing to be able to do, but I can't figure it out or find it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sjoerd - Thanks for your answer. I've been using CTRL-D already, but I don't want to have to do that extra step. It should be do-able with just a CR, no? BTW, I use linux.

Comment: @LokiAstari - You say that the code can be used when the input buffer is flushed, which you can accomplish by hitting enter. But that is exactly what I want to have happen and it doesn't. When I hit enter it goes to a newline and waits for more input.