# Get an index of every element in an array

Tags: c++

Using C++, I am reading a text file into a char Array using fgets, now I want to get an index of every element in this array.i.e. line[0]= 0.54 3.25 1.27 9.85, then I want to return every element of line[0] in a separate array, i.e. readElement[0] = 0.54.
My text.txt file has this format: 0.54 3.25 1.27 9.85
                    1.23 4.75 2.91 3.23
Here is the code that I have written:

```
char line[200]; /* declare a char array */
char* readElement [];

read = fopen("text.txt", "r");
while (fgets(line,200,read)!=NULL){ /* reads one line at a time*/
printf ("%s print line\n",line[0]); // this generates an error

readElement [n]= strtok(line, " "); // Splits spaces between words in line
    while (readElement [1] != NULL)
  {
printf ("%s\n", readElement [1]); // this print the entire line not only element 1

  readElement [1] = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
n++;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: An alternative approach [How to put an input string from stdio into a vector, one word per container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062545/c-how-to-put-an-input-string-from-stdio-into-a-vector-one-word-per-container)

Comment: You said your coding in C++, but all I see is C.
It sounds like your text file has multiple values on each line.
Have you considered using a two dimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

readElement looks misdeclared.  Just declare it as a pointer to the beginning of a string:

```
char* readElement = NULL;
```

You aren't checking the return value from fopen either.  That's the most likely problem.  Hence, "line" is garbage when you pass it to printf if the file didn't actually open.

And if you actually want to store each element of the line into an array, you need to allocate memory for it.

Also, don't name your variable "read".  "read" is also the name of a lower level function.

```
const size_t LINE_SIZE = 200;
char line[LINE_SIZE];
char* readElement = NULL;
FILE* filestream = NULL;

filestream = fopen("text.txt", "r");
if (filestream != NULL)
{
    while (fgets(line,LINE_SIZE,filestream) != NULL)
    {
        printf ("%s print line\n", line);

        readElement = strtok(line, " ");
        while (readElement != NULL)
        {
             printf ("%s\n", readElement);
             readElement = strtok (NULL, " ");    
        }
      }
    }
    fclose(filestream);
}
```

Comment: Thanks selbie for you fast reply, but I want to store each line of the text file in an array then make use of each element later on in my program. i.e. i want to read this row line[0]= 0.54 3.25 1.27 9.85, then extract one element of this array using readElement[0] = 0.54. How to achieve this? Cheers

Comment: You first need to count how many elements (numbers) are in the line, then allocate an array appropriately sized to hold each.  Then each element of the array should be appropriately sized as well to hold each string.